# Is it possible to get observable before transformation via operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Is it possible to?

### More verbose question

I have something like this:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(500);
const transformed = source.mergeMap(() => Rx.Observable.timer(100));
```

`transformed` observable is *new* observable and it is not connected to initial observable `source` (I can not access it through `transformed`, as I think). Is it possible to somehow get *initial* (before operator applying) observable after transforming with operator?

### My case

Code:

```
@AppendLoader()
@Effect()
getFriends$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(friendsActions.GET_FRIENDS)
  .switchMap(() => {
    return this.friendsService.getFriends()
      .map((data: any) => new friendsActions.GetFriendsSuccessAction(data))
      .catch(() => of(new friendsActions.GetFriendsFailureAction()));
  });
```

And AppendLoader:

```
function AppendLoader() {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    let observable: any = null;
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => {
        console.log('get');
        return observable;
      },
      set: (newObservable) => {
        console.log('set', newObservable);
        observable = newObservable;
        observable
          .subscribe((action: any) => {
            console.log(action);
          });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

I have three observables there:

- `this.actions$` (all actions)
- created from this.action$ `this.action$.ofType(friendsActions.GET_FRIENDS)` (observables of `friendsActions.GET_FRIENDS` type)
- third observable (2nd and `switchMap` applied to it) (observables of `GetFriendsSuccessAction`/`GetFriendsFailureAction`)

I have access only to 3rd observable in the decorator since this observable is in the `getFriends$` property.

I want to do some actions in the AppendLoader decorator. I want to subscribe to 2nd observable in the list and when value is emitted I want to show load spinner (`showLoader()` for example). And I want to subscribe to third observable and when success/failure value is emitted I want to hide load spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm briefly checked RxJs5 source code seems it's not possible.
But for your case, you can do the following:

1. Create new observable 'forDecoratror$':

   ```
   second$ = this.actions$.ofType(friendsActions.GET_FRIENDS)
   getFriends$ = second$.switchMap(() => {...});

   forDecoratror$ = Observable.Merge(second$.mapTo("2nd"), getFriends$)
   ```
2. In decorator call showloader() when "2nd" comes

Just keep in mind everything is a stream :-)

Comment: Yes I came to the same solution. I have two separate two observables and use extra observable to append decorator.

Comment: Anyway I used another approach to implement what I need. I think this way is not obvious and easy